# Whatsapp bot using Twilio and Flask- Wait for Reply

Tags: python-3.x, flask, twilio

I was building a WhatsApp bot using Twilio and Flask. So what should I do to make my WhatsApp bot wait for user reply and then execute the rest of the code. For example, my bot asks the user yes or no, the bot should wait for a reply, and based on the message received execute the rest of the code.

```
msg = request.form.get('Body')
resp = MessagingResponse()
msg = resp.message()
msg.body('Yes or No')
return str(resp) 
{Wait For Reply}
if msg == 'yes':
    do something
else:
    do else
```

I am a begginer at Python.Please Help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: And tell the user to say yes or no if the user doesn't replies

Comment: And too if the user replies before it asks, then do something else

Comment: Please tell me  ...please